# How to change width of a div by using jQuery in terms of percentage? for ex- to double the div's size upon mouse click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've come across methods to change div size by px, em and points. But couldn't find any way to do the same by percentage.

Answer (score 2):

In jquery it is possible to set dimensions to div based by the following

$("#whatever").css("width/height", "x%");

ref
http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName-value

or you can use dom itself
document.getElementById('whatever').style.width = 'x%';

Comment: what do you mean by 'ex- to double the div's size upon mouse click'? The posted answer is for 'How to change width of a div by using jQuery in terms of percentage?'

Answer (score 0):

Like this?  Find the current size, then multiple the dimensions by a number equivalent to the percentage.

```js
$('div').click(function() {
  //var h = $(this).height();
  var w = $(this).width();
  $(this).animate({
    'width': 2 * w,
    //'height': 2 * h
  }, 'slow');
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```